# Delete a symbolic link when the original folder is deleted

Tags: linux, bash, shell, symlink, delete-directory

I was thinking of using inotifywait to watch the original folder where the original folders are in, then whenever it detects that a folder has been deleted, then delete the same symbolic link in the other folder.

So my question is, is that the best way? Or are there better ways to delete a symbolic link when the original folder gets deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have not used inotify, but if it can integrate *nix's find command, you can use it to delete the link

```
find /folderpath -type l -delete
```